# What are the bounds of std::minstd_rand?

Tags: c++, random

From header `<random>`, there is an engine called `std::minstd_rand`.

Are the bounds for this engines random numbers inclusive or exclusive? It's got `min` and `max` functions, but I specifically want to know whether the random simulation can equal `min` or `max`, as opposed to just be bounded by them.

Documentation uses the word "between", which is of course not unambigous.

Comment: From [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine) `min` "gets the smallest possible value in the output range" and `max` "gets the largest possible value in the output range". From that wording I would assume both of those values would be inclusive.

Answer (score 4):

> t's got `min` and `max` functions, but I specifically want to know whether the random simulation can equal `min` or `max`.

Yes.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine#Characteristics (emphasis mine):

> `min [static]`
>
> gets **the smallest possible value** in the output range
>   (public static member function)
>
> `max [static]`
>
> gets **the largest possible value** in the output range
>   (public static member function)

Answer (score 2):

I think that we can be a little more precise.

As you can see `std::minstd_rand` is really `std::linear_congruential_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 48271, 0, 2147483647>` hence the emphasis of my co-answerer.

To simply check that indeed the generator can produce the value returned by `min() max()` we can use this simpler generator.

`std::linear_congruential_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 3, 0, 5>`

If we test it

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::linear_congruential_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 3, 0, 5> gen;

    std::cout << (std::uint_fast32_t) std::linear_congruential_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 3, 0, 5>::min() << std::endl;
    std::cout << (std::uint_fast32_t) std::linear_congruential_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 3, 0, 5>::max() << std::endl<< std::endl;
    gen.seed(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << gen() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

we get

```
1
4

3
4
2
1
3
```

As you can see the generator did hit the min and max. So

> min [static] gets the smallest possible value in the output range (public static member function)
>
> max [static] gets the largest possible value in the output range (public static member function)

The generator follows this rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator .
So basically min() returns `1` and max() returns `m-1`. No smarter than this.

If I take another generator `std::linear_congruential_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 3, 0, 6>`

and test it

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::linear_congruential_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 3, 0, 6> gen;

    std::cout << (std::uint_fast32_t) std::linear_congruential_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 3, 0, 6>::min() << std::endl;
    std::cout << (std::uint_fast32_t) std::linear_congruential_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 3, 0, 6>::max() << std::endl << std::endl;

    for (int s = 0; s < 6; s++)
    {
        gen.seed(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            std::cout << gen() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
1
5

3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3
```

Whatever the seed the output is always 3. so much for hitting the `min` and `max`

To finally answer the question

> Are the bounds for this engines random numbers inclusive or exclusive?

I don't know. It depends. And I don't know if somebody has ever proved that for whatever seed, you eventually always hit `min` and `max` for the  `std::minstd_rand` generator… But that is more of a mathexchange question...